# Unit test wrapper for URLSession completer

Tags: swift, testing, signature, urlsession

I have defined my own class with methods that fits signature of URLSession complete callback, e. g. `(Data?, Response?, Error?) -> Void`.
The method contains common logic for handling response, e. g. checking data, parsing it etc.
Now I would like to unit test this method. The methods contains some verification, for instance,

```
guard let data = data else {
    //some logic
    return
}
```

Here I would like to test that function will really be terminated. Of course it is not possible to achieve it against void return (I think so, maybe I missed something). 
Another option - mark the method as `throws`, and then test for a specific errors. But then this method will not fit into `URLSession.shared.dataTask` method.
Am I paranoid about these things? Is there any possibility to achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I try to separate the query logic into several parts:

1) Router 2) API client which uses a router 3) mapping model

And all this parts you can test.

**How you can test API client:**

```
fileprivate func testPerformanceOfGetNewsFromAPI() {

        let expectationTimeout: Double = 30.0

        self.measure {

            let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Get gifters")

            NewsAPIClient.getNews(closure: { response in
                expectation.fulfill()
            })

            self.waitForExpectations(timeout: expectationTimeout) { error in
                XCTAssertNil(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

This test will check. Could APIClient receive an response within 30 seconds.

**How you can test mapping:**

> For mapping, I use JASON: https://github.com/delba/JASON

Setup your swift file:

```
import XCTest
import JASON
@testable import ProjectName

final class NewsTests: XCTestCase {

    // MARK: - Properties
    fileprivate var news: News!

    // MARK: - Lyfecycles
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        news = mockExample()
    }

    override func tearDown() {

        news = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }
}
```

Then, create in this class your mock:

```
 fileprivate func mockExample() -> ExampleModel? {

        let data: Data

        let json: JSON

        do {
            try data = Data(resource: "MyExampleFile.json")  // Here enter your JSON example file. Target member ship for this file should be your test target

            try json = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as! JSON

        } catch let error {
            XCTFail(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }

        let model = ExampleModel(json: json)

        return model
    }
```

Then, you can write test in this class:

```
fileprivate func testMapping() {

        XCTAssertNotNil(news)
        XCTAssertEqual(news.title, mockExample()?.title)
        XCTAssertEqual(news.text, mockExample()?.text)
        XCTAssertEqual(news.timeStamp, mockExample()?.timeStamp)
    }
```

In the testing logic, you can also add image uploads (if they are present in JSON). Thus, you can check if the current model is correct for you, can process the JSON response.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. But I think it is not exactly what I asked for. I have also separated request flow into logical parts. And I need to test if request completer will be terminated if some of part is failed (e. g. wrong HTTP code, invalid response that can not be parsed e. g.). If flow does not stop if something wrong then I can get run time error. Thanks.